# Digression and Preprocessor digression nodes

Tags: node.js, dasha

What are digression nodes and preprocessor digression nodes? I would like to know the difference between the different nodes along with a few use cases. I would also like to know about it in depth as to how different nodes can be used for different purposes and where.

Answer (score 0):

Digressions are nodes, that can be executed from each other node without transition definition.

The best usage for them is handling common questions or reactions, for example, you have intent what_is_you_name and your user can ask it from any part of the conversation.

Just add

```
digression what_is_your_name
{
    conditions
    {
        on #messageHasIntent("what_is_your_name");
    }
    do 
    {
    #sayText("My name is Joe");
    return;
    }
}
```

The runtime system will check all the conditions of your current node transition and all the conditions of digressions, find the best match (using priorities if you have more than one match), and execute it;

You can:

- stop conversation using exit, for example, if you have detected swear words
- return to the execution point (the latest executed wait) using return keyword
- go to another node using wait operator. Regular digression can have transitions.
  Another type of digressions is preprocessor digression

All the preprocessor digressions will be checked and executed before and transition or regular digression.
You can use them to extract data from NER to your variables or can be used for external NLU.
For example you want to extract time and city entities to your context variable

```
preprocessor digression selectTime
{
    conditions { on #messageHasData("time"); }
    do
    {
        set $time = #messageGetData("time")[0]?.value;
        set $updateFilter = true;
        return;
    }
}

preprocessor digression selectCity
{
    conditions { on #messageHasData("city"); }
    do
    {
        set $city = #messageGetData("city")[0]?.value;
        set $updateFilter = true;
        return;
    }
}
```

And then, you can use regular digression, that will be fired on each set of updateFilter

```
digression updateFilter 
{
    conditions {on $updateFilter;}
    do
    {
        set $updateFilter = false;
        //do some stuff witch checking time and city
        if ($time is null)
        {
            #sayText("What time do you prefer?");
            return;
        }
        if ($city is null)
        {
            #sayText("What city do you want to visit?");
            return;
        }
        var time = $time ?? "";
        var city = $city ?? "";
        set match = external checkCityAndTime($city, $time);
        if (match)
        {
            #sayText("We have found tour for you");
        } else
        {
            #sayText("We have no tours to the " + city + " at " + $time);
            #sayText("Please select another time");
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

In this example, you can catch such phrases like

- I want to visit  at
- I want to visit
- I want to visit at 
  Another usage of preprocessor digression is for using external NLU

```
type NLUResponse = {
  hasSwearWords: boolean;
  hasMyIntent: boolean;
  myEntityValue: string;
};

context
{
    myNLUResponse: NLUResponse;
}

external function myNLU(string: text): NLURespone;

preprocessor digression myNLU
{
    conditions { on true; }
    do
    {
        set $myNLUResponse = external myNLU(#getMessageText());
        return;
    }
}

digression myReaction
{
    conditions { on $myNLUResponse.hasMyIntent; }
    do
    {
        //do whatever you want
        return;
    }
}
```

And you can implement using of another dialogue system with this trick

```
external function myDS(string: text): string;

digression myDialogueSystem
{
    conditions { on true; }
    do
    {
        var response = external myDS(#getMessageText());
        #sayText(response);
        return;
    }

}
```

SDK Part:

```
app.setExternal("myDS", async ({text}, conv) => 
{
    if (text == "help")
        return "How can I help you?";
    //You can call another dialogue system here using HTTP or another system    
    return "I don't know what to do";
});
```